# How can I make a hash function if I pass in a generic type?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

I'm trying to write a hash function that takes in a generic type. However, what I have, which is:

```
protected int hash(T key){
    return key % table.size();
}
```

gives me an error: "operator % cannot be applied to type T". I tried casting, still didn't work. How can I do this?

PS: this is in Java

Comment: Which language is this? Usually you’ll let `T` define its own hashing mechanism (`key.hashCode() % table.size()`).

Comment: it's written in Java